# Reseting to default after MoveEverything addon

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Does anyone know how to reset to defaul UI after removing MoveEverything addon? Target of target is in the wrong place and now I can't move it. The chat bubble is also too big.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset to the default UI by deleting your "WTF" folder in the World of Warcraft programs directory. The folder will automatically regenerate the next time you launch the game.

The folder contains all custom settings, so you will be reset to the base game. Anything stored on the server will be preserved (including macros).

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the target of target frame you should be able to unlock it and move it to wherever you like. (I'm assuming you're not using any other type of party/raid frames).

In terms of the chat bubble, if you mouse over the chat tab you should be able to right click on the tab and select unlock. After that you can re-size the window by using the bottom right hand corner of the window.

Comment: U got it both wrong ... My target OF TARGET is shifted, not target unit frame. Also for the speech buble is one like in comic books, above ur character, not chat frame.

Comment: I apologize that I misunderstood the question. Could you please provide a screenshot of what you mean? If everything is default (assuming no UI addons) could you just be zoomed in too much for the speech bubble? The default WoW chat bubbles are a set size. Unless you install an add-on it will appear that way. If you want to go back to complete default (like you just installed WoW) you'll need to remove a few files/folders to do a complete reset.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the size of your chat window in WoW you can simply right click you main chat tab and bring up the options and reset them. There is a safe that says this will remove all customization you have to click yes and it will be back to the way it is when you first install WoW. Not sure how to fix your target of a target, but hope this helps.